# Why is this destructuring not working?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I am creating an observable like so:

```
return new Observable(sub => {
    const {next, complete, error} = sub;

    this.AuthHttp.get(`http://192.168.1.100:3000/api/users/${id}`)
        .subscribe(res => {
            let user = res.json();
            next(user);
            complete();
        }, e => {
            error(e.json());
        });
})
```

Yet it nothing is happening in my front end when `next()` is expected to be called. If I make a minor change to the code so that `sub.next()` is called instead, everything works as expected. This indicates the underlying code is not flawed, just the way I am making a reference to `next`.

I have seen this form of destructuring used with the Observer class before (in an example online), so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that for this you don't need to be creating an observable like this at all. You could achieve the same with builtin operators (catchError, map).

Comment: The true implementation is a little more complex and does some caching. But you have given me some ideas. I need to spend some more time studying the builtin operators, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `next`, `error` and `complete` methods are object methods that **must be called on an object instance**.

When you use destructuring to obtain the functions and later call those functions, the calls are without context.

You cannot do what you've attempted for the same reason that this will not work:

```
const { toString } = new Date();
console.log(toString());
```

For more information, see [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3842).

Comment: Of course! Seems very obvious now, thank you! I will have to try and dig up the example I remember and perhaps point out this for them.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it just never safe to pull methods off an object instance? Or in other words, how do we determine when a method is an *object method* ?

Comment: A function can only be extracted and called without a context if the function in question does not use `this` in its implementation. So it'd only be 'safe' if you know that's the case and that the situation will not change.

Comment: That really answers the underlying question here, my curiosity is definitely sated, thank you again for such a concise answer and helpful elaboration.